# XML image path in XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt

I have a xml file with an index of different video games. Inside of each I would like to have a tag cover with content being a path to the image file like:

```
<cover>img/swb.jpg</cover>
```

And later to be able to display it with my xsl file.
I'm fairly new to XML, so first thought was to try and do this:

```
<td><img src='<xsl:value-of select="cover"/>' alt="coverart" /></td>
```

Easy to figure out, this did not work. 2 hours of google didn't help me either.
What is the proper way to deal with this issue?

Will be very grateful for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use an attribute value template `<img src="{cover}" alt="coverart"/>` or construct the attribute using `xsl:attribute`:

```
<img alt="coverart">
  <xsl:attribute name="src" select="cover"/><!-- XSLT 2.0 and later -->
</img>

<img alt="coverart">
  <xsl:attribute name="src">
    <xsl:value-of select="cover"/><!-- XSLT 1.0 and later -->
  </xsl:attribute>
</img>
```